# Flask OIDC user login is true but token is None

Tags: python, flask, openid-connect

I am using  [Flask-OIDC library](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to perform user authentication to external service.

When the user login for the first time the ODIC library works well. I can see the user information and the Bearer Token generated from external auth.

The problem arise when i refresh the page. If I check the user log in status, the ODIC library tell me that the user is logged in but the token is `None`. See this code:

```
@pdo_route.route('/edit_pdo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@oidc.require_login
def edit_pdo():
  if oidc.oidc.user_loggedin:
     oidc.get_access_token() # is None
```

The `oidc.oidc.user_loggedin` return `True` but the `oidc.get_access_token()` is `None`.

This is my OIDC configuration:

```
{
'SECRET_KEY': 'secret',
'TESTING': True,
'DEBUG': True,
'OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
'OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
'OIDC_USER_INFO_ENABLED': True,
'OIDC_OPENID_REALM': 'flask-demo',
'OIDC_SCOPES': ['openid', 'email', 'profile', 'name'],
'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD': 'client_secret_post',
'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': app.config.get("OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For future users, check to see if you are running this with just 1 thread or multiple (gunicorn or such). If you are running with multiple threads, you need to update your credentials_store with a different impl that works across threads/instances.

I used redis with a super simple implementation like so:

```
class RedisCredentialsStore(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, sub, item):
        flask.g.redis.set(sub, item)

    def __getitem__(self, sub):
        return flask.g.redis.get(sub)
```